# Alluxio - How to check log4j version used in Alluxio release (alluxio-2.8.1)

Tags: security, log4j, alluxio

We are using Alluxio(alluxio-2.8.1), and very curious to see and understand what version of log4j used in it. Please suggest where we can get that information.

Answer (score 0):

1. According to this url https://github.com/Alluxio/alluxio/blob/master/pom.xml, log4j version may be 2.17.1.
2. Secondly, in the archive, you can found assembly director, extract  some-thing-server.jar and find log4j class.
3. Thirdly, may be you can extract from running log, or set log to `DEBUG`